# Difference between local built and that through eclipse rcp ide running app

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, nattable

[Screenshot: on monitor with scale 125%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKFFD.png)
I develop an eclipse rcp app and face a strange phenomenon. When run the app through eclipse rcp ide, the dropdown(Compobox from org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.widget) behaves in an expected manner on all monitor scales(100%, 125%,..): the menu direction is up when opened on the edge of the screen.
When run the local created app (exe) the dropdown behaves differently on 125%: the direction is down so the menu is hidden.
I use eclipse IDE 2022-12, java 17, plug-ins: Eclipse 4 RCP 4.26.0.v20221123-2302, Eclipse e4 tools: 4.26.0.v.20221111-1233 on Windows 10 Enterprise version 21H2
How can I solve this problem?

I have tried to copy plug-ins from the ide to my app, but could not get desired results

Comment: Which OS is this?

Comment: It's a visual thing, so please show screenshots of it. Please improve your question instead of commenting on it.